# News Slider CSS and HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a news slider for my site that I'd like to use but I have a little problem. After finishing the HTML and CSS I need the 'showcase' to rotate, now I have tried different instructions with Jquery but no luck at all. Can someone point me or help me create this?

Here's a picture of what I have achieved so far Picture : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lzakd.png

And here's a link to my site :http://www.unscspartanteamomega.com/hproto

and here's a link to a site using something similar to what I'm trying to achieve : http://home.jejaju.com/play/kids/

I'm new to jquery so I don't know much but if someone could help or point me to something useful, I will appreciate every little help. I've been working on this since last week.

Thank you :)

Comment: The one on this page : http://home.jejaju.com/play/kids/

Comment: This is how home.jejaju.com/play/kids/ is doing it, I put the relevant code in a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b374B/

Comment: But how can i apply that to my HTML and CSS, that's what  I want to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the jquery cycle plugin found here: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Then you just need to add the following javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.topNewsBlock').cycle();
});
```

Comment: Do I have to select the effect?

Comment: By default it will use the fade effect.  If you want to change, it is quite easy:  $('.topNewsBlock').cycle({fx:'scrollHorz'});  Here is a jsfiddle as an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/tcRCj/  and here you can find all the effects: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/browser.html   The cycle plugin will rotate whatever child elements.  In your case it will rotate out the divs.

Comment: Well something happened, at least something is moving but it's not working properly. I appreciate your help. Thanks See : http://www.unscspartanteamomega.com/hproto

Comment: See this : http://web.archive.org/web/20100120033512/http://www.bungie.net/default.aspx#

Comment: Your navigation should not be inside the .topNewsBlock and each slide should contain your heading and the photo.  I've updated this to help you with the process:  http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/tcRCj/

Comment: I'm sorry for my questions, I'm just a bit confused. is this a new design or can I apply that to my current CSS and HTML?

Comment: The example I sent is a strategy for implementing a pager that sits on top of a slider.  The CSS I provided is only an example.

Comment: I still couldn't get it to work. Could you help me? Please  Takea look here : http://www.unscspartanteamomega.com/ttp1